# How to find the image of a 17th century music instruments manufacture?

Tags: art, industrial-revolution

How to find on Goolge Images search an image of 17th or 18th century manufacture? The drawing (or lithography) was showing a hall with people sitting around and building music instruments. I have seen this image once but cannot find it anymore. Thanks for help!

Expected answers are example search entries or maybe someone knows this image. Similar drawings hints are welcomed as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one perhaps?

[image: Plate of Lutherie Shop in the Diderot Encyclopedia]

[Source](https://news.lib.wvu.edu/2016/06/27/wikipedia-of-the-18th-century-historically-significant-encyclopedia-by-diderot-at-wvu-libraries/)

If not try [visually similar image search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&tbs=simg:CAESzQEJ5q5nUucWQIkawQELEKjU2AQaAggDDAsQsIynCBpgCl4IAxImlAyMA2ycDWqSBMMKigOdBK4IyiuGOMU25Dj-N_14i4jm7Oc0rhTgaMGZy6x0ynHpiXiDNMjNyRvgeQ9iMDRho1oiPDrkWDa1v1jZRQvDx4s9HlbtwVyipWyAEDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIEY7G1XwwLEJ3twQkaMQoZCgdjYXJ0b29u2qWI9gMKCggvbS8wMjE1bgoUCgNhcnTapYj2AwkKBy9tLzBqancM&q=diderot%20encyclopedia&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1zf_iuK7UAhWGcj4KHcJTDfgQsw4INA&biw=1723&bih=1208)

I found this by starting a google image search for "Luthier engraving".

It is from *[Encyclopédie, ou dictionnaire raisonné des sciences, des arts et des métiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclop%C3%A9die)*, first published in 1751 and edited by [Denis Diderot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denis_Diderot).

Comment: that's ingenious! thank you - it is not the same and I cannot find by similar search, but I totally accept this one. If possible, please type in exact source for any case.